# Error after installing crispy form

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm new to django but after installing django crispy form with

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

and having added

```
'crispy_forms'
```

in my settings.py, I still have an Unresolved reference when I add

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
```

in my forms.py

Comment: Did you put a comma after 'crispy_forms' in your settings.py?

Comment: I tried with and without but without success... The crispy_forms is working well when showing the form, but it is only a probleem within pycharm

Comment: Well, INSTALLED_APPS is a list, so all apps must be separated by commas.

As for pycharm, check to see if the django-crispy-forms package shows as being installed under file->settings->Project: (yourproject)->Project Interpreter.  If it isn't showing up there, you might have not got it installed in a way that PyCharm recognizes it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem after installing django-crispy-forms via the console (not with pycharm itself)

The way I solved this problem was:

In pycharm open

**Settings** then **Project** -> **Project Interpreter**

- click settings (gear symbol on the upper right) select **Add**
- selected your current working environment from the **Base Interpreter**
- check **Inherit global site packages** as well as **Make available to all projects**
- click **ok**  now you are back on the **settings Project Interpreter**
- here click on the **plus** icon on the upper right
- in the **search-dialog** on the upper left search for django-crispy-forms
- install the package
- after installation close the dialog
- back on the **settings Project Interpreter** click **ok** (that will close the settings

It takes some seconds while pycharm is updating its settings. After that the message "Unresolved reference..." disappears

I have to say that I don't know if all steps mentioned above are necessary, however in my case they solved the problem.

Comment: I installed from the Pycharm terminal using `pip install --upgrade django-crispy-forms` and it showed unresolved reference in PyCharm when I added `'crispy_forms'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then I installed it through PyCharm as you outlined above (not the interpreter part, I was already setup there) and the unresolved reference went away. Maybe it's something to do with the Crispy Forms docs telling you to upgrade first before first installing?

Comment: i just had to check 'Make available to all projects' to resolve it